# Validation: "th start tag in table body."

Tags: html

```
<table>
<thead>
 <th>Table Heading</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>.....
</tbody>
</table>
```

When I try to validate this part of code, the validator returns this error:

```
 th start tag in table body.
```

The table template was copied from getbootstrap.com so I should assume it's valid. What's the problem here? Why is the validator returning this error, and how can I solve it?

Comment: Which page on getbootstrap was that taken from?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`th` is a table header cell - it needs to be within a table row (`tr`):

```
<table>
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>Table Heading</th> 
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>.....
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

The placement of your `<th>` element is correct aside from it needing to be placed inside a `<tr>` tag as well... as D Stanley mentioned.

This is the full HTML table formatting specified by W3C:

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
     <th>Month</th>
     <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tfoot>
  <tr>
     <td>Sum</td>
     <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
 </tfoot>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
     <td>January</td>
     <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

[W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_thead.asp)